# Is in L2 gas limit much higher than in L1?

Tags: gas, gas-limit, l2

Naturally, in a blockchain gas per transaction is limited, because block place and distributed calculating power are scarce resources.

Can you point me a Level 2 system, where the gas limit per transaction is dramatically higher (e.g. 100 times) than say in Ethereum mainnet?

If no, then what limits gas in L2? How much it is indeed higher?

If gas limit can be set high enough, I won't need to split transactions into parts.